# Rxjava2/RxAndroid2, dispose (looking for an equivalent for rx1 unsubsribe)

Tags: android, dispose, rx-android, rx-java2, unsubscribe

This is my first time developing in reactive paradigm world, and i started using rxjava2/rxandroid2, as based on videos I've watched and articles I've read, it seems like its better to start with 2 as 1 has so many changes that differs the library in a big scale, but now I'm having some trouble looking for something that acts like the

```
 unsubscribe()
```

method of the former rxjava/rxandroid library

my goal is just quite simple

- perform an API call(network operation)
- listen and react on what the observable will emit (happy path)
- do not listen or react when app goes to PAUSE state
- or, unsubscribe on observable as soon as android goes to the pause life-cycle

, based on the resources around there is

```
 dispose()
```

method of rx2, what I understand with this is that it disposes any current resources(in my case, base on what i understand, invoking this will make the observable detach itself to any observer).

but that doesn't seem to be what I'm expecting, please have a look at the ff codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Disposable disposable = new Disposable() {

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            Log.e("Disposed", "_ dispose called.");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDisposed() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Observer<Object> observer = new Observer<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.e("OnSubscribe", "On Subscribed Called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object value) {
                Log.e("onNext", "Actual Value (On Next Called).");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.e("OnComplete", "On Complete Called.");
            }
        };

        EventsApiService.getInstance().testApi().testCall()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnDispose(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        Log.e("Disposed?", "__ Dispose");
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(observer);

        observer.onSubscribe(disposable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        disposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

I'm having this output:

```
03-23 09:08:05.979 3938-3938/edu.rx.study E/Disposed: _ dispose called.
03-23 09:08:13.544 3938-3938/edu.rx.study E/onNext: Actual Value (On Next Called).
03-23 09:08:13.544 3938-3938/edu.rx.study E/OnComplete: On Complete Called.
```

I was expecting that onNext won't be called anymore or maybe both onNext and onComplete, but that doesn't seem to be working, am i missing something here? or theres something i totally don't understand, my thinking with my code is,

"what if onNext is performing something towards a widget(UI)(Observer) and the app goes on **pause** state?", I don't want that UI(Observer) to react on that particular UI anymore.

Many people are right, and I admit, switching to reactive programming is quite hard especially rxjava2/rxandroid2 has a very steep learning curve.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're handling incorrectly the `Observer` and the `Disposable`, the `Disposable` object should be handing to you by the Observable, you can't just create it by yourself, and call explicitly `Observer.onSubscribe()` with it, as it's not connected to the `Observable` and does not terminates it.
(you can also notice that `Observer.onSubscribe` is called twice, one by the `Observable` and one by you)

What you should do, is simply use the `onSubscribe(Disposable d)` method at your `Observer` to save the `Disposable`, which will be called automatically by the `Observable` and will hand you the correct Disposable object, that you can successfully terminate the network operation with it.

Another option is, to not use at all the [subscribe(Observer o)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.Observer)) method, but other overloads that takes your [onNext](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer))/[onError](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Consumer))/[onCompleted](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Action)) as parameters, and returns `Disposable` object, which you can dispose (unsusbcribe) with it, for terminating the network call.

Comment: "What you should do, is simply use the onSubscribe(Disposable d) method at your Observer", thanks for this, i took the disposable parameter from the onSubscribe implementation and reference it to a disposable variable, and it worked!, but, just to add some question regarding with this, is this the same with Subscription.unsubscribe of the rx1? , in rx2 I cant find a similiar .subscribe (i,e subscribes back to the observable), so the only thing i can do is to recreate/re-do all the steps/code again?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean, but Disposable.dispose is like Subscription.unsubscribe of RxJava1

Comment: sorry, I think i replied quite long. I mean, the only way to subscribe back is to re-subscribe again? like, existingObservable.subscribe() ? or just create another observable and subscribe a new one?